# Installing SharePoint 2013 on local Domain

Tags: sql-server, domain

I'm trying to install SharePoint 2013 for our company.

We already have a Domain Controller running on a separate Windows Server 2003.

I am creating a separate server (Windows Server 2008 R2 x64) to install SharePoint 2013 and SQL Server 2012 on.

Will I be able to install and configure SharePoint to work with my Domain/Child-Domains and Domain Users?
If not, what are the alternatives that I have?

Do I have to join the SharePoint server (Windows Server 2008 R2) to my existing domain before I begin the installation of SharePoint and SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint is able to use Windows Authentication as it is running on IIS.  As a rule of thumb, the machine should be joined to the domain prior to running any enterprise level software install.  Both SQL Server and SharePoint have ways to change the domain they are on, but they are not short processes.  It is easier to install correctly the first time.

The link below is to a TechNet article that gives a good overview of the process of installing SharePoint on a single server and has links within it to go to the least-privileged security model.

[Install SharePoint 2013 on a single server with SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262243.aspx)

Hope that helps.